# XML .xsd invalid element

Tags: c#, xml, xsd

hi I have some xml which i am trying to use with a schema i've created but when i try and parse the xml i get the error message below:

```
The element 'PartnerPSTNTransfer' in namespace 'http://localhost/Orders-PartnerPSTNTransfer-v1-0' has invalid child element 'InstallationAddress' in namespace 'http://localhost/Orders-PartnerPSTNTransfer-v1-0'. List of possible elements expected: 'Configuration' in namespace 'http://localhost/Orders-PartnerPSTNTransfer-v1-0'.
```

Below is my XML that i have created and the schemas related to it:

XML:

```
<p:PartnerPSTNTransfer xmlns:padsl="http://localhost/Orders-PartnerPSTN-v1.0" 
                       xmlns:p="http://localhost/Orders-PartnerPSTNTransfer-v1-0" 
                       xmlns:a="http://localhost/Orders-Address-v1-0" 
                       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
                       xmlns:c="http://localhost/Orders-Connection-v1-0">
  <p:TelephoneNumber>01224507392</p:TelephoneNumber>
  <p:StartDate>2014-10-25</p:StartDate>
  <p:Postcode>co27pe</p:Postcode>
  <p:InstallationAddress>
    <a:NameNumber>10</a:NameNumber>
    <a:Line1>Somewhere Road</a:Line1>
    <a:City>Somewhere City</a:City>
    <a:County>Somewhere County</a:County>
    <a:Postcode>co2 7pe</a:Postcode>
  </p:InstallationAddress>
  <p:Configuration>
    <padsl:Package>Data Only</padsl:Package>
    <padsl:Feature>F0 F1 F2</padsl:Feature>
    <padsl:Contract>Monthly_12</padsl:Contract>
  </p:Configuration>
</p:PartnerPSTNTransfer>
```

PartnerPSTNTransfer xsd:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema id="PartnerPSTNTransfer"
    targetNamespace="http://localhost/Orders-PartnerPSTNTransfer-v1-0"
    elementFormDefault="qualified"
    xmlns="http://localhost/Orders-PartnerPSTNTransfer-v1-0"
    xmlns:mstns="http://localhost/Orders-PartnerPSTNTransfer-v1-0"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:a="http://localhost/Orders-Address-v1-0"
    xmlns:padsl="http://localhost/Orders-PartnerPSTN-v1.0"
    xmlns:c="http://localhost/Orders-Common-v1-0"
    xmlns:conn="http://localhost/Orders-Connection-v1-0">

  <xs:import namespace="http://localhost/Orders-Common-v1-0" schemaLocation="../../Common.xsd" />
  <xs:import namespace="http://localhost/Orders-Address-v1-0" schemaLocation="../../Address.xsd" />
  <xs:import namespace="http://localhost/Orders-PartnerPSTN-v1.0" schemaLocation="PartnerPSTN.xsd" />
  <xs:import namespace="http://localhost/Orders-Connection-v1-0" schemaLocation="../Connection.xsd" />

  <xs:complexType name="PartnerPSTNTransfer">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="TelephoneNumber" type="c:Landline" />
      <xs:element name="StartDate" type="xs:date" />
      <xs:element name="Postcode" type="c:RequiredString" />
      <xs:element name="InstallationAddress" type="a:Address" />
      <xs:element name="Configuration" type="padsl:PartnerPSTNConfiguration" />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:element name="PartnerPSTNTransfer" type="PartnerPSTNTransfer"></xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

PSTNTransfer xsd:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema id="PartnerPSTN"
    targetNamespace="http://localhost/Orders-PartnerPSTN-v1.0"
    elementFormDefault="qualified"
    xmlns="http://localhost/Orders-PartnerPSTN-v1.0"
    xmlns:mstns="http://localhost/Orders-PartnerPSTN-v1.0"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:a="http://localhost/Orders-Address-v1-0"
    xmlns:c="http://localhost/Orders-Common-v1-0" >

  <xs:import namespace="http://localhost/Orders-Common-v1-0" schemaLocation="../../Common.xsd"/>

  <xs:simpleType name="Contract">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:token">
      <xs:enumeration value="Monthly_12"></xs:enumeration>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>

  <xs:simpleType name="PackageOption">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:enumeration value="Data Only" />
      <xs:enumeration value="Evening and Weekend" />
      <xs:enumeration value="1000 Anytime" />
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>

  <xs:simpleType name="FeatureOption">
    <xs:list>
      <xs:simpleType>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
          <xs:enumeration value="F0"/>
          <xs:enumeration value="F0A"/>
          <xs:enumeration value="F0B"/>
          <xs:enumeration value="F0C"/>
          <xs:enumeration value="F1"/>
          <xs:enumeration value="F2"/>
          <xs:enumeration value="F2A"/>
          <xs:enumeration value="F3"/>
          <xs:enumeration value="F3A"/>
          <xs:enumeration value="F3B"/>
          <xs:enumeration value="F3C"/>
        </xs:restriction>
      </xs:simpleType>
    </xs:list>
  </xs:simpleType>

  <xs:complexType name="PartnerPSTNConfiguration">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="Package" type="PackageOption" />
      <xs:element name="Feature" type="FeatureOption" />
      <xs:element name="Contract" type="Contract" />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

I have the InstallationAddress element declared in the right place before the Configuration element so am confused as to why it would throw this error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `xsi:schemaLocation` to hint to the XML processor that the XSD for the `http://localhost/Orders-PartnerPSTNTransfer-v1-0` namespace is `PartnerPSTNTransfer.xsd`:

```
<p:PartnerPSTNTransfer xmlns:padsl="http://localhost/Orders-PartnerPSTN-v1.0" 
                       xmlns:p="http://localhost/Orders-PartnerPSTNTransfer-v1-0" 
                       xmlns:a="http://localhost/Orders-Address-v1-0" 
                       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
                       xmlns:c="http://localhost/Orders-Connection-v1-0"
                       xsi:schemaLocation="http://localhost/Orders-PartnerPSTNTransfer-v1-0  
                                           PartnerPSTNTransfer.xsd">
```

After making the above change and *stubbing-out the dangling references to XSDs not included in your question*, I am able to validate your XML file.  Perhaps an older version of your XSD is getting picked up from an unexpected location on your hard drive.  Be careful with outside XML catalogs or other tool mechanisms for associating XML document instances with XSDs.